# Deep learning with Amazon instances: where do you/how do you upload your data to train?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have an incredibly basic question. I have set up an AWS EC2 instance for deep learning purposes and I am using `Jupyter` notebooks. I can't find clear literature on how to upload my data to be trained (large batch of images).

EDIT:
From my research, I can see how you could upload your image files to an Amazon s3 bucket, but this is ridiculously slow for 100ks of large image files for Deep Learning. Is it possible to point to a folder on your local machine (Mac) from an Amazon instance (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Upload data from where? You want to upload through `Jupyter`?

Comment: Data on my own machine so it's accessible to my Jupyter notebook running on my EC2 instance. I'm beginning to realise I need to upload the images to an s3 bucket and point to that in my notebook.

Comment: So basically you don't want to spend the time to upload your data to amazon? I really don't think any deep learning model would realisticly be trainable with INTERNET data transfers from disk to memory... 
What is the size of your dataset (in GBs?)

Comment: This is what I was thinking. So where do you upload your data to, so it's accessible to your Amazon instance? I'm sure it's a basic question - it's just I cannot see any literature on the specific question of images

Comment: I believe you should upload your data to S3 in order to access it later on from your container.